# Managing local nuget depedencies in single .sln

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I created a solution containing 2 DLLs that are published as nugets. I took Hangfire as an exemple.

So, if I have a DLL named hangfire and a second one hangfire.sql, this mean hangfire.sql depends on hangfire. hangfire.sql is refering hangfire as a nuget and not a project dll. Then, even if I specify the dependency in the .sln, I get an error when I build the solution saying the first nuget couldn't get restored.

Is it doable? The alternative I see is hangfire.sql to use the version already published of hangfire and not the version present in the .sln

I'm on Visual Studio 2019

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by adding dotnet restore in the .csproj as follow:

```
<Target Name="NuGet restore" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
    <Exec Command="dotnet restore" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 should do this already. VS 2019 definitely does this. Which VS version are you using?

Comment: Hi Boubou, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :) And since VS2017 and higher version will do the restore by default, I suggest you can add the version info to your answer. (This workaround should work for specific vs versions)

Comment: I was using VS2019